# Test flight not sending invitation emails to internal testers

Tags: ios, testflight, app-distribution

I have developed a mobile application in flutter and I want to ship this application to test flight for testing. Everything has worked fine. I created a group for internal testers and invited them for testing but none of them is getting invitation for testing on test flight. What should I do? I have exhausted all the solutions available online and none of them is working for me.

I have tried adding and removing users over and over again and re-sending the invitations. The dashboard of test flights says that the invitaions has been sent, but no email received. What could be the potential reason for this behavior.

Comment: oh man, I face the same issue. Reported a bug in feedback assistant. Tried re-add users to a group and to account as well. Nothing helped.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/5802?page=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I added capabilities like Push Notifications and Apple Sign-in in Xcode as well as in the Identifier tab of Apple Developer Account. When I re-signed the app with the updated provisioning profile and with updated capabilities in Xcode, the invitation emails were sent immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Invitation mail is sent when you add your build to test phase. To do so, you have to  go into you Internal Tester Group and add the build you want to be tested.

After that, every member will get and email with an unique code to insert into TestFlight app and then they can test the application.
This email is sent only to user that haven't inserted any code to TestFlight yet

Comment: I have added the build to be tested by the group. I have noticed, I don't receive any single email from testflight regarding any update.

Comment: Maybe it's just a bug